# Eclipse: How to do a low level installation using dropins directory

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, subversive, eclipse-marketplace, eclipse-photon

Following is the directory structure of plugin I want to install in eclipse.

Eclipse version: photon.

Organization I work at has restricted access to http sites. Only https is accessible. So I cannot install plugins from eclipse marketplace. I have a zip of Subversive SVN connector and this is the only way it can be done I think.

I was able to install Subversive using install software but unable to do so with Suversive connector.

Is it possible to install Subversive connector using dropins directory of eclipse?

[image]

Comment: It depends. If it is a ZIP of the update site (does the `features` subfolder contain JARs and not subfolders?; and does the root folder contain a `content.jar` or `content.xml` file?), you have to use _Help > Install New Software..._ instead.

Comment: Yes. features subfolder contains JARs and root folder contains content.jar. Also I am unable to install it through Help > Install New Software. Though I was able to install Subversive in this way but it is not working for the connector.

Comment: Why you are unable to install it? Please note, your screenshot shows pretty old connectors (from 2013). There are also two very similar SVN plug-ins for Eclipse: Subversive and Subclipse (I guess, both with their own connectors) which should not be mixed. If HTTPS works, does the update site `https://ssl-proxy.my-addr.org/myaddrproxy.php/http/community.polarion.com/projects/subversive/download/eclipse/6.0/update-site/` (via [this HTTP to HTTPS proxy](https://ssl-proxy.my-addr.com/)) work?

Comment: Yes. It works. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.

Found this site for SVN connector and installed it from there.

https://community.polarion.com/projects/subversive/download/eclipse/6.0/update-site/?dir=features